# What to answer CBP at airport while re-entering home country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens

I am a naturalized US citizen of Indian origin. I will be flying to India & Sri Lanka soon for 12 days. I am in the process of building a software application for which I have hired 2 remote freelancers. I have been dealing with them for over a year now and I consider them more as friends than just employees. Upon my return to the United States, should I just say to CBP officer that the purpose of my trip was vacation or I should explain all the things?

I do have a valid LLC company which I operate using my home address. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just answer the questions. Don't forget that as a US citizen, they cannot deny you entry, so the only reason for any questions is to make sure that you are really who you say you are, and I doubt they would have any questions about what you were doing abroad, or even where you were. It should be very quick.

Comment: @jcaron there is another possible purpose to those questions, which is the customs investigation.

Comment: @jcaron, Usually CBP almost always inquire about purpose of visit. I travel at-least once out of country every year for pleasure. I know most likely I can just ditch them saying I was on vacation, however a part of me says it's unethical to lie specially to CBP.

Comment: @Ronny it's also [against the law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1001), though you are exceedingly unlikely to be prosecuted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a (native-born white male) citizen, I find that CBP officers rarely ask the purpose of my trip.  (If they do ask, you can even refuse to answer under the fifth amendment, although that is probably not a good idea.)

The answer you should give depends on something you have not disclosed in your question, which is whether you will be doing any work while you're on the trip.  If the purpose of the trip is even in part to visit the freelancers to discuss things related to your business then it doesn't matter whether you consider them "more as friends," because they are still also your employees, and the purpose of your trip is still at least partly business.  Some options for your response, depending on the circumstances, include:

- "business"
- "mostly vacation, but I also had some business meetings"
- "vacation"

As noted in a comment, however, the answer is probably not too critical.  Because you are a US citizen, you cannot be denied entry.  If you answer in good faith, you will probably not be prosecuted under [18 USC 1001](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1001).  On the other hand, if the officer thinks you're being evasive, you could very well be selected for secondary customs screening, which could include a thorough search of your possessions.